# How do I make a character that looks like the Courier in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, recently, I have had an obsession for making other characters in Skyrim (eg. Farkas, Vilkas). I want to make the courier character (I honestly don’t know why, lmao) but I can’t find any help on Google. If someone would please send me some instructions that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a new character that looks like the courier?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make a character build from YouTube called the traveler and I though a courier character would fit it quite well.

Comment: Trial and error is the only way I know. Even screenshots of the settings aren't reliable since the sliders can display differently depending on whether or not they are 'minimised'. Sometimes, some of them can even reset themselves when using the "showracemenu" command. The only thing to do, in my experience, is to just continually try till you get the look you want. This can be very frustrating but I know of no other way.

Comment: I don't really feel like writing this all out as an answer, but you should follow this guide: https://levelskip.com/rpgs/How-to-Make-Your-Skyrim-Character-Look-Like-Any-Character-in-the-Game#:~:text=duplicate%20the%20character%20you%20want,profit